# Triple integral validation

Tags: integration

is it correct that the following integral is, actually, a triple integral of the variable $r$?
(it has to do with electromagnetic calculations)
The integral is symbolised with a single S integration symbol (integration to "everywhere" -meaning- to all the area the charge extends- then comes the function $f(r)$ where $r\ge 0$ and the integrity element is not dr but $d^3r$. Note that the $f(r)$ function is actually a product of two functions which are both able to be integrated seperatedly, and are continuous functions.

$$\int_D f(r) \, d^3r,\qquad   r>0$$

The above are referring to Green's theorem.
Thank you.

Comment: I can't see the integral!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral is over three dimensional space.

I assume that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. 
In a common abuse of notation, $d^3r$ is an [infinitesimal volume element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral). 
There are many ways to parametrize such an integral.
In Cartesian coordinates the volume element is $dx dy dz$. 
In spherical coordinates, which seem to be relevant to your problem, it is $r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$. 
<strike>See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Spherical_coordinates) for more details. 
(Note that $\rho$ on that page is your $r$.)</strike>
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) is a better link that follows our convention for spherical coordinates.